# PineScript: whats wrong with my brain? (too many alerts)

Tags: pine-script

maybe someone can help me, there is something wrong in my understanding of PineScript:

This alert is triggered exactly once (which is the expected behavior)

```
  if(someOtherCondition)
    //some other code here
    someOtherCondition := false
    executionStage := 1 
    alert("setting execution stage to 1", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

BUT: the following one triggers every single second, despite the condition does not evaluate to "true" after the first trigger. The alert gets then stopped because of "too many triggers"

```
if(executionStage == 1)
  //some different code here
  
  if(close >= someThreshold)
    executionStage := 2
    alert("setting execution stage to 2", alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if(executionStage == 2)
  //more code
```

Can you tell me whats wrong? In my opinion, it should only trigger once, because the condition "executionStage == 1" is not true anymore after the first alert.

There seems to be something completely wrong in my understanding of the evaluation of conditions, despite I am programming for over 20 years in ANSI C language.

Thank you very much in advance!

Additional info:

- "calc_on_every_tick" is set to "true"
- "executionStage" is defined as "var int executionStage = 0"
- the alert itself is set to "alert() function calls only"

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: try to declare `varip int executionStage = 0`